# Broken image path on Vercel deployment

Tags: reactjs, image, deployment, vercel

I'm deploying an app on Vercel and everything builds correctly except for my header image. I just get the name of the image file. When I open the app through react on the local server, the logo image shows up as it should. Any ideas? Right now the image in just in the public folder in react. I have another image in the same folder and it is showing up just fine on the page. The logo is also a link to the main page, and if I click on the broken file name, the link works. I am using router.

I tried changing the file name, I tried putting the images in a folder and doing a path instead of the image name, and I changed the Navlink to a Link.